# Rich Edit EM_SETPARAFORMAT fails when text mode is TM_PLAINTEXT

Tags: winapi, richedit

EDIT: this question is significantly edited based on further investigation of the problem.

I am working on a program API that displays programmatically created rich edit controls. It allows the caller to specify whether to use plain text or rich text like this:

```cpp
void SetUseRichText(bool state)
{
    DWORD textMode = SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_GETTEXTMODE, 0, 0);
    if (state)
    {
        textMode &= ~TM_PLAINTEXT;
        textMode |= TM_RICHTEXT;
    }
    else
    {
        textMode &= ~TM_RICHTEXT;
        textMode |= TM_PLAINTEXT;
    }
    SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_SETTEXTMODE, textMode, 0);
}
```

The primary goal of this setting is to prevent text in the control from picking up the formatting of text pasted into the control. It would be nice if the program itself could modify the formatting beyond the font (which it can and does modify).

I have run into an issue where I would like to be able to control the line spacing of the text in the control. I have this code to do it:

```cpp
    PARAFORMAT2 pf{};
    pf.cbSize = sizeof(pf);
    pf.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
    pf.bLineSpacingRule = value ? 3 : 0; // use twips, but no smaller than single-space
    pf.dyLineSpacing = std::lround(value * 20.0);
    SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&pf));
```

The problem is that if the caller has set the control to `TM_PLAINTEXT`, then `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` does not work. (The SendMessage returns 0.) I guess my quesion is multi-part.

- Is there a way to control the line spacing of a `TM_PLAINTEXT` rich edit control? Perhaps some way that is not using messages specific to the control?
- Given that `TM_PLAINTEXT` and `TM_RICHTEXT` are bit-values, what does it mean of both are set? (Or if neither are set?)
- Should I take a different approach to prevent formatting from being pasted in?

Comment: I figured out the problem. The ones that are failing have their text mode set as `TM_PLAINTEXT`. So my question comes down to 1) is there a way to control the line-spacing of a plain-text control? 2) What does it means when both `TM_RICHTEXT` and `TM_PLAINTEXT` are set (or neither)?

Comment: Have you seen the remark on `EM_SETTEXTMODE`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-settextmode#remarks Plain text controls, on the other hand, do not need the default, end-of-document marker, so it is omitted. So it has evidences that cannot change its line-spacing. Emmm, sth interesting will let you understand it. Can you change line-spacing in notepad? It does not have the feature.

Comment: Thanks. That comment adds clarity to what TM_PLAINTEXT does. I'm guessing if both TM_PLAINTEXT and TM_RICHTEXT are set, it either chooses one or ignores them.

Comment: I bring some news. Check my answe pls.

Answer (score 0):

**About setting `TM_PLAINTEXT` and `TM_RICHTEXT`.**

I found a mistake If you want to set `TM_RICHTEXT` and `TM_PLAINTEXT` on text, you need use `CHARFORMAT2W`. `PARAFORMAT2` just set the paragraph formatting. I already tested it.
[image]

If you set `CHARFORMAT2W`. It always displays character formatting  of a rich edit control. Whatever you set one of them, both of them and none.
[image]

It also can change the line-spacing when richtext and plaintext exist.
[image]

Here is my code, hope it helpful.(Modified)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc
(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // Must load rich edit library
    }
    case WM_SETTEXT:
    {
        LoadLibrary(L"riched20.dll");

        HWND hWndRichEdit;
        hWndRichEdit = CreateWindow(RICHEDIT_CLASS, NULL,
            WS_CHILD | ES_SAVESEL | ES_NOHIDESEL | WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_BORDER
            | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_EX_STATICEDGE,
            0, 0, 300, 200, hWnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);

        CHARFORMAT cf;
        ZeroMemory(&cf, sizeof(CHARFORMAT));

        PARAFORMAT2 pf;
        pf.cbSize = sizeof(PARAFORMAT2); 
        pf.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
        pf.dyLineSpacing = 600; //
        pf.bLineSpacingRule = 4;

        LRESULT res3 = SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, LPARAM(&pf));     
        LRESULT res4 = SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_SETTEXTMODE, TM_PLAINTEXT, (LPARAM)&cf);
        LRESULT res5 = SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)L"555");
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
int APIENTRY wWinMain
(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nCmdShow
)
{
    wchar_t szAppName[] = L"TestRicheditCharFormat";
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass;

    wndclass.cbSize = sizeof(wndclass);
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, L"Hello, world!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 300,
        NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

**Edit**:New rules as you said:[image]
Also modified the code.

Comment: Doesn't `yHeight` set the font size? I don't want to change the font size. I just want to modify the line spacing.

Comment: @rpatters1 Of course! Just set `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` in `SendMessage`. Why you changed it failed before. Because `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` is just targeted to charcter not paragram.

Comment: @rpatters1 I edited my answer again as your requirement.

Comment: So you are setting both `TM_PLAINTEXT` and `TM_RICHTEXT`. What does this mean to set them both? The docs I read don't address this case, and they seem to imply that you should set one or the other. I appreciate the effort in this answer, but it would be more helpful if it just addressed the line spacing issue.

Comment: @rpatters1 I just set them both as your requirement to show you. If it is a rich edit control, `TM_PLAINTEXT` does not mean for anything. You shall see docs, `CHARFORMAT` and `PARAFORMAT2` both for rich edit control.

Comment: Just to be clear: I now understand that `TM_PLAINTEXT` does not allow to change the line spacing. That doesn't mean it makes sense. Plain text per se does not imply that the line spacing should be immutable. Plain text describes the content whereas line spacing is part of the display. I accept, however, that MSFT has decreed it so.

Comment: @rpatters1 I found something new. I can set line spacing when setting `TM_PLAINTEXT`! Just as my code showing. I ignored the pic1, it is what you want.

Comment: I see `TM_PLAINTEXT | TM_RICHTEXT` in your code. If you can get it to work with just `TM_PLAINTEXT`, please post an example the omits all the character formatting and just shows the answer to the question. I appreciate your continued efforts.

Comment: @rpatters1 Already done. Check the answer again.

Comment: I am struggling to integrate your example into my code. Every time I send `EM_SETTEXTMODE` with `TM_PLAINTEXT`, it reverts the line spacing to the default.

Comment: @rpatters1 Why don't you just post your code,a ,minimal reproducible sample in your question?

Comment: @rpatters1 You can just use my code without modification. If it still reverts the line spacing to the default, we can comfirm there are some problems on IDE or other things.